# Python First Project: Algorithm that find a book and its author from a quote

Tags: python

I hope this is the good site for my question.

I am new with Python and I am neither a programmer nor a data scientist. I would like to code an algorithm that given a book quote can find the book's name and author.
Do you have any suggestion/sources that can help me with my project?

I think that the simplest approach will be to include in my code the Google Books API. In fact, it is really difficult to find a large database including Books' text in order let the algorithm research the quote. Do yo agree with my first approach? Which are the limitations of using Google APIs? Can I share my code with other users or they will be not able to use it because of some kind of Google restriction?

I am sorry for the stupid questions, but I have just begun this adventure in Datascience and I think that the best way to learn is to fix some objectives and not just to do courses.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a data science project. It's more a programming problem as you are trying to build a program with multiple functions to gather data, sort data, etc.

Data science is about finding, researching, analyzing relationships within data itself. Data scientists don't work on APIS, neither SQL or other data sources (but it doesn't mean they don't know about it).

https://stackoverflow.com/ should be a right place for your question, specially if you have some code. I am sure they will help you there with Google API

Comment: Thank you @Stenga ! Unfortunately, I have already asked on Stack Overflow and on Software Engineering but in both the site they said to me that I am off-topic.

Comment: if you have some python code on stackoverflow, this should not be an off-topic.

Comment: @CarseppeGiudone I guess they misunderstood your question. At first glance I thought your question was about teaching a computer to recognize the writing style of an author, which would be a machine learning problem. But all you are trying to do is query the Google Books API for a quote, that's on-topic for StackOverflow. As Stenga said, you should include some of your research and/or code when you ask there.